# Is it possible to create an Excel custom function to autocomplete strings using an API?

Tags: office-js

I'm building an Excel add-in to interact with a few APIs that serve data on plant species.

One of the things I want to implement is a custom function that auto-completes species names as I type from the suggestions of an HTTP response.

I want to click on a cell, start typing a plant name and have the function detect the `onChange` cell event, send a new query to the API and display the most likely plant name on another cell.

As I keep typing, I want the function to make new queries and update the suggested name if needed.

I understand I could achieve this with React and the taskpane, but is it possible at all to implement a custom function to provide this functionality?

There are around 120k plant names in the dataset, so a data validation list wouldn't work.